# xslt table fixed columns

Tags: linux, xslt

This is my xslt table code. I would like to have fixed columns for name, size date. I want to control the widths of these columns in the code without having the columns size according to data. Thanks.

---

```
  <h1><table border="0">
     <tr bgcolor="#1E90ff">
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Size</th>
         <th>Date</th>
     </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="list/*">
     <xsl:sort select="@mtime"/>

         <xsl:variable name="name">
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:variable name="size">
             <xsl:if test="string-length(@size) &gt; 0">
                 <xsl:if test="number(@size) &gt; 0">
                     <xsl:choose>
                             <xsl:when test="round(@size div 1024) &lt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="@size" /></xsl:when>
                             <xsl:when test="round(@size div 1048576) &lt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="format-number((@size div 1024), '0.0')" />K</xsl:when>
                             <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="format-number((@size div 1048576), '0.00')" />M</xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                 </xsl:if>
             </xsl:if>
         </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:variable name="date">
             <xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,9,2)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,6,2)"/>-<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,1,4)"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
             <xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,12,2)"/>:<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,15,2)"/>:<xsl:value-of select="substring(@mtime,18,2)"/>
         </xsl:variable>

     <tr>
         <td valign='top'><img src='/.icons/unknown.gif' alt='[   ]' width='16' height='16' /><a href="{$name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a></td>
         <td align="left"><xsl:value-of select="$size"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="$date"/></td>
     </tr>

     </xsl:for-each>
  </table></h1>
```

---

Comment: XSLT doesn't have "tables", you can use XSLT to output HTML or XSL-FO, both have tables and allow you to define the dimensions of columns, see any HTML and CSS tutorial on HTML tables, in HTML there is a `col` element for instance for column-wise declarations.

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was looking for

```
<tr>
 <th width="70%">Name</th>
 <th width="19%">Size</th>
 <th width="11%">Date</th>
</tr>
```